# iPhone/ARM calling convention

Tags: iphone, assembly, calling-convention

on iPhone/ARM, which CPU registers are functions supposed to preserve, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia's article on [Calling Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM) has a good summary of the conventions for ARM.

Comment: On all OSes - the same convention? I find that hard to believe. On x86, dozens of conventions exist.

Comment: The writers of the article made a nice reference to this in the section on x86, calling out how it is noteworthy in having so many (mostly due to its lack of registers), and providing a separate article explaining them. Wikipedia's discussion of the topic is about the most complete I've seen, and provides more discussion of why the x86 has such a hodgepodge of solutions compared to other chips. In short: in the early days of x86 (unlike other chips) there were several compiler vendors who went different ways. But today, even on x86, there is a strong move to standardize the ABIs.

Answer (score 3):

Old, but incorrect answer. Wikipedia is often inaccurate (sometimes downright incorrect), and this is an example of the former case. There is a generic calling convention (which is what Wikipedia documents), but OSes can deviate - both Android and iOS do (and likely Win 8 will, but we'll know that when the binaries start surfacing)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iPhoneOSABIReference/Introduction/Introduction.html 
provides the correct spec for iOS, so no sense in repeating here. Most notably, note the use of r7 and r12. Also note that ARMv6 and ARMv7 are different. By now, you want ARMv7 architectures (A4,5,6..)

Comment: Different use of R7 does not break the ABI, but just debugging tools. An important difference between iOS ABI and EABI is alignment of 64-bit arguments: iOS uses 4-byte alignment, while EABI uses 8.